# php string translator API

Tags: php, string

Is there any API which can convert translate my string into another language.

I have string `$string="hello world"`.  I want to convert only hello world to urdu language.

Is there any API or SDK for this?

Comment: unfortunately, requests for a ["tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) might help you edit your question to get better answers, or perhaps consider [migrating the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site#85041) to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/)..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google translate](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/translating-text-with-rest#Translate)

```
$translate = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&target=ur&q={$string}");
```

Comment: how can i get API key ? actually it is paid i think.